# Can I transfer compressed data to GPU then decompress on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to send large, sparse matrices for computation to the GPU, and much of the compute time is spent transferring data from CPU to GPU. My data, however, is actually very sparse (lots of zero values), so I had the idea of compressing it significantly pre-transfer to help alleviate the bandwidth bottle-neck. Is this feasible in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Does the SparseTensor class or cuSPARSE library meet your needs?  It is definitely possible to convert to a format such as COO, CSR or CSC.

Comment: SparseTensor is part of the library and documented, but unfortunately I am on the road and can’t test amything right now.